# How do I extract data by filtering on a list of criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2008

I have an Excel problem that I don't know how to approach.  Let me explain the scenario.

Column A is populated with Name, which has both First & Second Name. I need to filter records based on multiple criteria, skipping those Names that contain an apostrophe [ ' ] symbol or a number, and copying those that contain neither to column B.

For example:

```
  Col A                Col B

  Henry 'James'                     (Contains apostrophe)
  Henry Peter          Henry Peter  (No apostrophe or number)
  Henry PP123                       (Contains number)
```

According to this example, only Henry Peter should be copied.

There are many obvious ways to do this if it requires testing for a single condition.  In this case, there can potentially be any combination of numbers and/or apostrophe, contained anywhere in the column A value.  So there is a substantial list of conditions to test for in each cell.

Is there a way to do this that does not require an insanely complicated approach?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Have a hint, check out FIND()...

Comment: Readers, the downvotes and close votes might be a little harsh on this question.  Solutions are findable Googling with the right terms, but those terms may not be obvious, and this isn't a trivial problem that can be solved in a simple way.

Comment: A variation on yass's solution described [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things).

Comment: Suggestion to ALL just MENTION the REASON you DOWN VOTE the ANSWER will help me to improve !!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula, if your Data start in A2, in B2 write:

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"'"},A2))>0,"",A2)
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> It is an array formula.

```
Col A            Col B 
Henry 'James'    =IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"'"},A2))>0,"",A2)         
Henry Peter     Henry Peter
Henry PP123
```

The formula will find 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"'" and count will be >0 it will write nothing "" in B2
Copy the formula down the column it will change automatically and when the count =0 it will write A2 (the corresponding cell value).